# System.Xml.Linq dependency on unsigned System.Core

Tags: f#, .net-framework-version, f#-fake

In an F# executable targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2, an XML file is loaded, modified, and then saved back to disk via System.Xml.Linq:

```
let doc = XDocument.Load apiDoc
...file is modified....
doc.Save apiDoc
```

After moving the project from Visual Studio 2015 to Forge/FAKE/IonIDE with:

- windows-sdk-10.0 10.0.26624
- visualfsharptools 4.0
- microsoft-build-tools 15.0.26228.0
- visualstudiocode 1.11.2

The following error is encountered:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the 
file specified.
   at System.Xml.Linq.XText.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(String fileName, SaveOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(String fileName)
   at Migrate.main(String[] argv) in c:\Projects\Migration\src\app\Migration\Migrate.fs:line 133
```

I have tried adding the following before loading the document, with the same error occurring:

```
Assembly.Load("System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089") |> ignore
```

Notes:

- Framework versions 3.5 and 4.5.2 through 4.7 are installed on the Windows 10 development machine.
- Identical behavior occurs on a Windows 2012 R2 server with Framework versions 3.5 and 4.5.2 through 4.6.2 installed.
- FSharp.Core.dll is distributed with the executable.

This confuses me as 4.6.2 does not have a 3.5 dependency, and the expected reference given in the error does not have a strong name.

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of me learning the VSCode/Ionide.  When first setting up the project, System.Xml.Linq did not resolve.  I made the mistake of adding it to the paket.references file with no version constraint.  This prompted Paket to pull down the [Mono package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.Linq/).  Being a version 3.5 package, it has an implicit dependency on System.Core, version 3.5.

After removing the package from the project, and then using the intended F#: Add Reference command within Ionide, the correct 4.6.2 Framework reference was added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

For those working with an FSharp script, you can reference the assembly and then open `System.Xml.Linq`:

```ml
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open System.Xml.Linq
```